# Should I validate input if I don't care?

Tags: validation, type

I am developing an application where a user will store arbitrary key-value pairs. The value is of no interest to the application, as it will merely be stored and returned at a later moment. The user will be given the option to decide the 'type' for the value.

This type can then be used in order to provide keyboard settings, such as numerical keyboards on smartphones, or offer visual clues, such as icons.

A potential reason for *not* enforcing a correct input pattern would be minor annotations or sums, such as these examples:

```
1145 (in 2014)
13 * 17
about 80
```

It could be argued, however, that information like this should be stored separately, or another field type should be used.

When a user has selected a type of `number` for the value he/she'll be providing, **should I enforce this type**?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking without seeing what it'll be used for.

Comment: An example would be a note-taking app. The value to be entered could be a number, date, color, etc...

Comment: What is it later returned to the user for? Just to see what they entered, or is there another reason?

Comment: If it's a "note-taking app" then there's absolutely no reason to validate it, as they should be able to note whatever they want. But if it's more specific like a DOB, location, etc. then validate it. If you're asking for a number, validate it to make sure it's a number and not letters.

Comment: To see the entered value, yes. It may be used for other applications, but it will never be considered reliable input.

Comment: Why are you giving a type if you don't care?

Comment: Why/how is the 'type' important to your application? If it's important, then likely you do need to validate. If not, then there's no need.

Answer (score 4):

It is always bad idea to enforce validation until you're absolutely sure you're doing a right thing, since enforcing validation may be harmful: for example, some of e-mail validation algorithms still doesn't know that "+" is allowed inside username part of e-mail addresses and that really hurts some users.

So, *unless value correctness isn't critical for your app, I think that it's better to let users enter whatever they want* and keep using value type only as a hint.

Comment: While that's true for e-mail addresses, it's fairly easy to validate numbers and letters for names, phone numbers, addresses, etc. For e-mail addresses, everybody should know about http://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php.

Comment: @CodeMaverick you're right, but are there any reasons to add all of these types and let user to choose exact type (phone number, for example) from the long list if we could give her a more generic "number" type, show a numeric keyboard by default and let  enter whatever she wants (not a "phone number" but "price" or something else)?

Comment: I'm just saying that since the OP said, "The user will be given the option to decide the 'type' for the value," then it's only right to validate against the type they choose.  But sure, it's all relative to whether the OP cares or not.

Comment: Yes, the inability to use a '+' in email address fields is incredibly annoying (and still seemingly widespread).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a specific type, then you should validate and only accept that specific type.  If you are just storing strings, then you could get away with just basic empty string type validation if you wanted to.  But, yes, I always recommend validating when you know what you should be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

> To see the entered value, yes. It may be used for other applications, but it will never be considered reliable input.

Just because you at the moment don't want to do anything with the value doesn't mean that a future developer of your application wouldn't want to do anything with it.

Assuming that something will never be considered reliable input is a strong assumption. If a developer looks at a dataset with 100000 rows and 1000 that he randomly checks contain numbers, he might treat the dataset as containing numbers.

Developers do make errors from time to time and when unvalidated content is thought to be validated that can result in the application being able to be attacked via SQL injections.

> An example would be a note-taking app. The value to be entered could be a number, date, color, etc.

Having validated dates is pretty useful for a note taking app. It means that I can ask questions such as: "Do I have any notes about date XY?" without having to think about how the date is formatted. It moves the problem to detecting data formatting to the time where it belongs, when the user enters the data.

Someone might develop a calendar plugin that displays notes that have to do with a particular date when the calendar page for that date is opened. If you do validate your dates you allow other people to develop such software that builds on your own software.

Google Now might be interested in some cases to give you an card that related to the note for the date.

It reasonable behavior for a function in some library that takes a color value to crash when given the string: "the color of an apple". Even worse it might not sanitize the value and directly pass it into a html statement. That means an attacker could use it as a vector to pass active Javascript into the page.

If I input a number into an note taking application I want to note the same thing if I note: "1 233", "1,233" or "1233". I would want freedom to enter the number as I want but on the other hand have 1233 stored in the database in all cases. If the application is more complicated there might very well be a setting to display "1233" stored in the database as "1,233". "0.2" and ".2" should both input the same thing into the database.
If a user types 13 * 17 into the field and you want to look into that use case store 221 in the database.

I [do](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/selbstvermesser-kleineidam-die-digitalisierung-des-ich-a-778467.html) Quantified Self myself and at the moment use Google Forms. If I would switch to an Android App for data capture I would expect that App to normalizes the data I put into it, so that I don't have to worry about data normalization at the point where I analyse my data.

If I tell a data capture app about the types that my input is supposed to have, I want it to do the job of normalizing the data.